# Compiling a RISC-V code using GCC compiler

Tags: gcc, compilation, riscv

I am trying to compile a `RISC-V` `C` code into hex or binary file. I found out that the GCC-GNU compiler might help me. 
On the [wiki page of gcc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection), under`Architectures`, there is a list of available targets and there, we can find:

> Additional processors have been supported by GCC versions maintained separately from the FSF version:
>   ...,...,...RISC-V

Does this mean that is it not supported? That i have to install something else? If yes, what and how can i do that?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://riscv.org/software-status/#c-compilers-and-libraries

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Thanks, there are few links, the best for me would be compiler with "rv32gc clang", so.. any idea which link to use?